# Linux iptables reserve number of connections for given rule

Tags: iptables, firewall

Is there a way to reserve a number of connections (from a total of nf_conntrack_max) for a given traffic rule?

I am trying connlimit but the problem is that is consumes 100% cpu for instance when there are many P2P applications/clients.

Maybe use hashlimit with connlimit? What is the the norm in this type of situation.

Thanks